# npm/git: best practice for linking/adding example projects to library?

Tags: javascript, git, npm

I published a library on npm. I would like to add some example projects using this library to its repo. These projects have their own git repos.

What's the best practice to do that? Do I:

- Add their code to the library's repo, and repeat this every time I update these projects?
- Add the urls to the git repos of these examples projects in the library's README.md?

Comment: Repeat what every time? Why add projects to a library repo? - I personally would prefer adding the links to the readme.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing - just adding links to these projects in the library's readme. What I meant in the first option was that I would have to copy-paste and commit any changes to these example projects in the library's repo if I went with this option.